# Faster way to assign new values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if there is faster way to assign new values to cells in a pandas dataframe conditional on the value of another cell.  For example, take this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rank':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'condition':[.01, .01, .01, .01, .01, .01, .01, .01]})
```

The following code works:

```
def changerank(row):
    if (row['condition'] == 0) & (row['rank'] > 1):
        row['rank'] = 1
    return row

df = df.apply(changerank, axis=1)
```

But it is rather slow on my real dataframe containing millions of rows.  I feel like there may be another way to change the values of 'rank' depending on values of row.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.ix`:

```
df.ix[(df.condition==0) & (df.rank>1), 'rank'] = 1
```

I believe `loc` may also work instead of `ix` here.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote you but awesome.  That was exactly what I was looking for!  Way faster.

Comment: Attention: df.ix is deprecated. ipykernel_launcher.py:3: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing